# Infinitely many deformation equivalent Hodge diamonds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Let $S$ be a connected open complex manifold. Let $\phi:X\to S$ be a proper holomorphic submersion with connected fibers. Can the fibers of $\phi$ have infinitely many distinct Hodge diamonds?

An example of varying Hodge diamonds is given in the paper "Complex parallelisable manifolds and their small deformations".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because $h^i(\Omega_{X,s}^j)$ is upper semicontinuous in the analytic Zariski topology. So it can attain only a finite number of possible values over $S$.